# fourier transform of cumulative function

Tags: st.statistics, fa.functional-analysis

Hi

I've encountered a test that uses the cumulative value of a finite time series to deterime the data set's stationarity.

I would like to know the characteristics of this test in frequency space, so would therefore need to know the fourier transform of this cummalative function.

I was assuming that the function could be writen as the product of the initial time series function, f, and a heavyside step function, H.  With the defining function written as:

$g(t) =  \sum^{t}_{n=1} f(n)  H(t-n) $

I would like to know fourier transform of the function g(t).  Is there a straightforward solution to this function or does the use of the discontinuous step function make a solution impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Read

Discrete-Time Signal Processing (2nd Edition) (Prentice-Hall Signal Processing Series) [Hardcover]
Alan V. Oppenheim (Author), Ronald W. Schafer (Author), John R. Buck (Author)

and all will be revealed.